# How to do operations depending on the presence of a specific string in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, math

I am working with a csv file, so imagine I have this column:

5;10;>11;20;<14

My desired output would be:

5;10;12;20;13

So I would like to add +1 to those values who have the greater than (>) symbol and to subtract 1 to those values with a lesser than (<) symbol with bash language. I have tried something weird with sed but given that it interprets those changes as strings it didn't work out.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

With `awk` (tested with GNU `awk`):

```
$ awk -F\; -v OFS=\; '
{
  for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
    if($i ~ /^<[[:digit:]]+$/) {
      sub(/^</,"",$i)
      $i--
    }
    else if($i ~ /^>[[:digit:]]+$/) {
      sub(/^>/,"",$i)
      $i++
    }
  }
} 1' <<< "5;10;>11;20;<14"
5;10;12;20;13
```

Warning: use the following if and only if you trust your input file and you are 100% sure it does not contains malicious fields (see the final note).

With GNU `sed` (and assuming your shell is `bash`), a bit shorter but also a bit more difficult to understand (as usual with `sed`):

```
$ sed -E '
s/<([[:digit:]]+)/$((\1-1))/g
s/>([[:digit:]]+)/$((\1+1))/g
s/.*/printf "%s\n" "&"/e
' <<< "5;10;>11;20;<14"
5;10;12;20;13
```

That is (where `N` is a string of digits), substitute all `<N` with `$((N-1))`, all `>N` with `$((N+1))`, substitute the resulting string `S` with `printf "%s\n" "S"`, execute it with `bash` and replace with the output (this is what the `e` modifier of the substitute command does). In your example the input string successively becomes:

```
5;10;>11;20;$((14-1))
5;10;$((11+1));20;$((14-1))
printf "%s\n" "5;10;$((11+1));20;$((14-1))"
5;10;12;20;13
```

The reason why there is a serious security issue here is that if one of your fields is, for instance, `$(rm -rf ~/*)` it will simply and recursively delete your entire home directory... So, if you do not control the input prefer the `awk` version.

Answer (score 0):

```
5;10;>11;20;<14
```

|

```
{m,g}awk '
BEGIN {
    _*=(OFS= "") (__-=_^= FS ="("(\
   ___="\31\17")"|"(____="\16\24")")+"
} {
    gsub(";[<>][0-9]+",____ "&" ___)
    gsub(____ ";[<>]", "&" ___)
    NF
    for(_+=(_^=($_=$_)<"")+_;_<=NF;_++) {
        if ($_~"^[0-9]+$") {
            $_+=__^($(_+__)~"[<]$")
        }
    } print $(_=_<_) }'
```

=

```
5;10;>12;20;<13
```